# Can't access my extension methods in another file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, extension-methods

I have this namespace in `Extensions.cs` file:

```
namespace TextBoxExtensions
{
    public static class TextBoxExtensionsClass
    {
        public static void ResetColor(this Label label)
        {
            label.ForeColor = new TextBox().ForeColor;
        }
    }
}
```

then:

```
using TextBoxExtensions;
```

//...

```
textbox.ResetColor();
```

when I try to access it in another file, I get the following error:

> 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'ResetColor' and the best extension method overload 'TextBoxExtensions.TextBoxExtensionsClass.ResetColor(System.Windows.Forms.Label)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Your extension method extends the `Label` class, not the `TextBox` class.

Comment: If you look closely, you will see that the compile error tells you what the problem is - that the type of your parameter doesn't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what type is `textbox`? your extention is for a `Label` object. I am guessing that this is your problem.... that your `textbox` object is not of type Label

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you've defined your extension method for the `Label` type but are attempting to call in on an instance of `TextBox`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead, this will allow you to use it for any type of control:

```
    public static void ResetColor<T>(this T control) where T : Control, new()
    {
        control.ForeColor = new T().ForeColor;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined your Extension Method for the `Label` class. You're then trying to use it on a `TextBox` which will, for obvious reasons, not work (the two classes have no relation to each other).